# How do I get gfortran to generate architecture specific predefined macros?

Tags: gfortran, preprocessor, predefined-macro

I want gfortran to generate architecture specific macros like __AVX__ and __AVX512F__ when it runs the preprocessor. If I run

```
echo | gfortran -march=tigerlake -dM -E -
```

I get all the predefined macros including the architecture specific ones printed to the screen. Now if I run

```
gfortran -c <somecode.F90> -march=tigerlake
```

gfortran runs the preprocessor with only a subset of the predefined macros. It seems like gfortran does not pass the -march=tigerlake flag to the preprocessor. This however, works with gcc.

See this long link [https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:'1',fontScale:14,fontUsePx:'0',j:1,lang:fortran,selection:(endColumn:20,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:20,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:20,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:20,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23if+defined+__AVX__%0A%23define+msg+%22Has+AVX%22%0A%23else%0A%23define+msg+%22Has+not+AVX%22%0A%23endif%0A%0Aprogram+AVX%0A++++implicit+none%0A++++print*,+msg%0Aend+program'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'Fortran+source+%231',t:'0')),k:31.01927062600148,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gfortran132,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',binaryObject:'1',commentOnly:'0',debugCalls:'1',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'1',libraryCode:'0',trim:'1'),flagsViewOpen:'1',fontScale:14,fontUsePx:'0',j:1,lang:fortran,libs:!(),options:'-cpp+-march%3Dtigerlake',overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'+x86-64+gfortran+13.2+(Editor+%231)',t:'0')),k:35.6473960406652,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:'x86-64+gfortran+13.2',editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:'0',j:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'Output+of+x86-64+gfortran+13.2+(Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:fortran,selection:(endColumn:20,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:20,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:20,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:20,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23if+defined+__AVX__%0A%23define+msg+%22Has+AVX%22%0A%23else%0A%23define+msg+%22Has+not+AVX%22%0A%23endif%0A%0Aprogram+AVX%0A++++implicit+none%0A++++print*,+msg%0Aend+program%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Fortran+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:31.01927062600148,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gfortran132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:fortran,libs:!(),options:%27-cpp+-march%3Dtigerlake%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gfortran+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.6473960406652,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gfortran+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gfortran+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

I get the result "Has not AVX". I should get "Has AVX".

Comment: I found out if I can run the C preprocessor cpp manually before compiling with gfortran it works, but it would be nice if I could get gfortran to do it automatically.

Comment: This sounds rather like a question to the gfortran developers to be asked at the official gfortran mailing list. Are these macros supposed to be set or not for Fortran? Alternatively, if you believe to be a defect to be fixed, you can open a new bug at the GCC bugzilla, but I would personally asked first.

Comment: Preprocessor directives are not a part of the language. But since they are set when using gcc, I would expect things to work the same with gfortran since both invokes the C preprocessor cpp.

Comment: Whst you expect does not really have to be the same what the developers decided to imolement or ensble. That's why it is best to ask and check. I repeat: "if you believe to be a defect to be fixed, you can open a new bug at the GCC bugzilla, but I would personally asked first."